# How to config UICollectionView's maxCellSpacing?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

We can congif  UICollectionView's min CellSpacing with  UICollectionViewFlowLayout's property `minimumInteritemSpacing`.

But we need also congif  UICollectionView's max CellSpacing sometimes.For example:

[image]

The first line and the second line is ugly,the third line is showed as my expect.

So I wonder can I config UICollectionView's max CellSpacing so that I can change the first line and the second show as the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I accomplished with a custom layout which inherit from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
class MaxCellSpacingLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var maximumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        if attributes?.count == 0 {
            return attributes
        }

        let firstCellOriginX = attributes?.first?.frame.origin.x

        if let count = attributes?.count {

            for i in 1..<count {
                let currentLayoutAttributes = attributes![i]
                let previousLayoutAttributes = attributes![i-1]

                if currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x == firstCellOriginX {
                    continue
                }

                let previousOriginMaxX = previousLayoutAttributes.frame.maxX
                if currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x - previousOriginMaxX > maximumInteritemSpacing {
                    var frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame
                    frame.origin.x = previousOriginMaxX + maximumInteritemSpacing
                    currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame
                }
            }

        }

        return attributes

    }

}
```